# OleDbCommand with Update query causes OleDbException

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbconnection

I found this problem when debugging the program:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

```
    cnx.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cnx;
    string idcarte = textBox1.Text;
    string name = textBox2.Text;
    string phone = textBox3.Text;
    string area = textBox4.Text;
    string date = textBox5.Text;
    string idcartecom = comboBox2.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Update Family set IDCarte=@idcarte,Name=@name,Phone=@phone,Area=@area,Date=@date where IDCarte=@idcartecom";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idcarte", idcarte);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area", area);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idcartecom", idcartecom);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnx.Close();
```

Please if there is a solution I will be thankful.

Comment: The sql looks good from here. Can you confirm the family table and all columns exist as you have them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the field `Date` in square brackets since it is a reserved word in OLE DB:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Family SET IDCarte=@idcarte,Name=@name,Phone=@phone,Area=@area,[Date]=@date WHERE IDCarte=@idcartecom";
```